# Load data infile

Tags: mysql, file-io, load

I need my program to have two enclosed characters. My strings in my file can be enclosed by either single quotes or double quotes. How may I manage that?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure this is The Answer... but I'd run it through `sed` to replace all the double quotes to single (or the other way around). You need to keep in mind escaping when writing your regex, though.

Answer (score 0):

Is it a csv or delimited file?  You can pick a delimiter and not worry about string enclosures (so long as the strings don't contain the delimiters).